# How to scroll md-dialog panel and don't close it?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Hi I am using angular material md-dialog manel.

```
    $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: 'rt.tmpl.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            controller: 'SomeController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            targetEvent: event,
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            multiple: true,
            fullscreen: self.isCustomFullscreen      
        })
```

As you can see I use  clickOutsideToClose: true (i need to have it).
But I have a scrollbar on right at same time  (see picture). Issue is that when I click on scroll the panel closes..
how to avoid it?

[image]

thanks in advance!!!:)))

Comment: Not sure that you can differenciate outsideToClose zonez and scrollbar

Comment: fixed it. wrote answer.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems basically to be a *CSS* problem. By default, the dialog has a max height and max width of 90vh respectively 90vw. So, if your content overflows the height of the dialog, the scrollbar should appear inside the dialog, not on the window.

Try setting the height of the md-dialog-content to 90vh minus the height of md-dialog-toolbar and md-dialog-actions:

```
md-dialog-content {
  max-height: calc(90vh - $mdDialogToolbarHeight - $mdDialogActionsHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it

```
   clickOutsideToClose: false,
```

and applied listener to md-dialog parent:

```
 var dialogContainerEl =  document.getElementsByClassName("md-dialog-container")[0];

            dialogContainerEl.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                hidePanel();
            });
```

it works fin now. thanks guys!